# Interactive PDF (for Mobile) - Is there a way to navigate to a page within a PDF and ensure that the user starts at the top of the page?

Tags: pdf, pdfpage

I'm creating an interactive PDF to be viewed on a mobile device (it's not an ideal option, but this is the direction we need to pursue).

Currently, I have tested buttons and hyperlinks, and I can easily navigate through the PDF. However, my view following the jump is centred on the page (content is cut off on the page above and below).

I have tried a variety of hyperlink anchoring types, but I'm not having any luck.

I thought the solution could be to use *navto://* within a *GO to URL* hyperlink, but I have been unsuccessful with that as well.

**Is there a way to navigate to a page within a PDF and ensure that the user is brought to the top of the page?**

Answer (score 0):

If you are willing to post-process the file, `cpdf -open-at-page <n> in.pdf -o out.pdf` should set this up, for a given value of `<n>`. See Chapter 11 of the manual for details.